# Magento URL Redirect from One product to Another product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, url-rewrite

After reading about *Magento URLs redirect*, I thought it would be simple and straight forward. When its time for an action, I faced nothing but disappointment.

***What do I need :*** I want to create a URL redirect from *PRODUCT A* to *PRODUCT B*, while *PRODUCT A* is disable.

***The problem I am facing:*** When I click *URL REWRITE* and choose `FOR PRODUCT`, I get a list of products in my store. I choose PRODUCT A. Afterwards, it gives me an option of choosing a category; I CHOOSE TO SKIP IT. On next page, it give me the option to rewrite. The only thing I can enter on the page is REQUESTED PATH, when I enter the NEW URL in to the REQUESTED PATH field, I get an error saying `Request Path for Specified Store already exists` the error is keep popping up over and over again. Do you know what other way I can edit PRODUCT A so it REDIRECTS to PRODUCT B.

I have attach images for your reference.
Thanks for your help!

[image: Clicked on URL Redirects]

[image: image 2]
[image]
[image: image4]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to use a `.htaccess` rule. You can open the .htaccess file and enter in the following code at the bottom. After you've finished working on your product A just remove the lines from the .htaccess file and save. It's all instant and doesn't require any cache refreshes etc.

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /product-a.html /product-b.html
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thanks for your help. I have another question. 
So the page I am trying to redirect is www.domain.com/view-product/chair.html%20 to www.domain.com/view-product/chair.html There is %20 in the URL and it seems to be not redirecting it to the URL Im trying to redirect. Do you know if %20 is the problem why this isn't redirecting. If so, do you know the solution behind it.

Comment: Never mind, figured it out!
Really appreciate your help.